# Arabic characters are shown in a generated PDF as black blocks in a Django project using xhtml2pdf

Tags: reactjs, django, pdf, markdown, pdf-generation

I am building a Django/React project with mySQl database which has a collation utf8_general_ci. I want to generate a PDF based on given data in Arabic using xhtml2pdf. When I generate the PDF I find that the Arabic Characters are shown as black blocks or squares although I am using charset utf-8 in the HTML file and in the rendering function itself and I am using a font that is written in the official documentation of xhtml2pdf that it can be used for Arabic content. I have also used many other Arabic fonts but nothing worked.

in utils.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from io import BytesIO
from fpdf import FPDF


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return HttpResponse('notworking')
```

in views.py:
from .utils import render_to_pdf
import io
from django.http import FileResponse
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def ResultList(request):

```
template_name = "frontend/thepdf.html"
theentry = entry.objects.get(id = 2)

return render_to_pdf(
    template_name,
    {
        "entry": theentry
    }, 
)
```

in thepdf.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
    
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        
        @font-face {font-family: RTLFont; src: url('/Markazi_Text/static/MarkaziText-Regular.ttf')}

        body {
            font-weight: 200;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: RTLFont;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

                <pdf:language name="arabic"/>
              <div>هذه هي التجربه </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have followed the steps for solving this like changing the charset to Windows-1256 and changing the fonts but nothing work. I have tried to use a React library but I found that It will be difficult to render markdown content inside the pdf as I am using a markdown content. So If there is a solution or other technique that I can use to solve my problem

Comment: I am facing the same issue and I could not find a solution. Any help, please?